# How does ancient and modern arbitration differ?

Tags: word-comparison, modern-life, legal-latin

There is a legal thing called arbitration in modern world, and the Romans seem to have had the word [*arbitratio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=arbitratio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
I wonder whether the modern arbitration and the Roman *arbitratio* (and the related words like *arbiter*) are similar in any meaningful way.

If I understand correctly, modern arbitration is all about using a third party which is not a court to solve disputes.
Does *arbitratio*, *arbiter*, or other related words have this flavour at all?
Or should I just think that one of the many legal Latin words was selected to name this modern legal arrangement?

This question was inspired by the [recently announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309746/321340) change to terms of service on this network (including Latin Language Stack Exchange).
The changes introduce arbitration, and that has caused quite a lot of unrest.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are quite identical. Lewis & Short has for arbiter (http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DA%3Aentry+group%3D68%3Aentry%3Darbiter):

"II. Esp. A. In judic. lang., t. t., prop., he that is appointed to inquire into a cause (cf. adire hiberna, Tac. H. 1, 52, and intervenio) and settle it; hence, an umpire, arbiter, a judge, in an actio bonae fidei (**i. e. who decides acc. to equity, while the judex decides acc. to laws**)."